# make HTMLPurifier omit double quotes around="attributes"

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

This is not terribly important, but I want to find out if you can possibly have HTMLPurifier omit the double quotes around arguments. When it filters HTML it usually reformats it into XHTML syntax.

But I would prefer `<div class=alphanum>` rather than `class="xyz"` in the output - whenever possible.

The config settings http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html provide no obvious option, and I didn't bother to look through the code (500K do scare you away). HTMLPurifier does use DOMDocument at some point. I'm not sure if this is just for pre-parsing, or if it's for output serialization (then I could answer the question myself with: No).

I've glanced through the [htmlpurifier](/questions/tagged/htmlpurifier) tag, found nothing. And enabling the experimental(?) `HTMLPurifier/Lexer/PH5P.php` parser doesn't change the *output* behaviour.

So is there an uncommon setting or tweak for that?

Comment: I know I could just use a regex after cleanup. But I shall better not write 
that here.  :} -- As for the use case: Just want to untrain the bad habit. 
I only have only one real XHTML site [= it's only true if you use the
correct mime type in my book].  And would prefer to use the SGML notation  
now that it is first class again.

Comment: It's actually not *bad habit* to use quotes. The W3C [recommends using quotation marks even when it is possible to eliminate them](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Comment: I accept that as the most authoritative advise. Still it can be a strain on readability (want to eschew), and it's technically not very necessary anymore now that most XML toolkits provide an HTML mode.

Comment: From my travels, I don't think it is possible, and I'm confident you will know how to write the regex to strip them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Purifier specifically quotes all of its attributes for security reasons. There is no knob to turn it off.

Comment: Conclusive answer. -- Was there a specific type of XSS exploit the quoting prevents?

Comment: One well known example is the fact that IE treats backticks as "quotation marks". In fact, there's no end to browser specific behavior when you lose the quotes, so HTML Purifier always puts them in.

Comment: OK. So it's general behaviour but purposed for non-alphanumeric attribute content. There's no concern in strictly `\w+` values?

Comment: I'd have to test to feel comfortable about that.